# Слайдер изображений на Java

Tags: java, gui

Добрый день! Возникла необходимость написать небольшое приложение для ПК по отображению jpeg снимков друг за другом. Можно ли это реализовать на Java в виде простого GUI? Если да, то подскажите пожалуйста какие библиотеки лучше для этого использовать?

Comment: такая задача просто и быстро - JavaFx

Comment: ok, спасибо! Буду иметь в виду.

Comment: JavaFX реально пока лучшее средство для подобных задач на Java. Вот здесь есть учебник: http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/ru/

Comment: Задачу можно решить с помощью 3D в javaFX. Просто Берём несколько ImageView и в них отображаем картинки, а сами эти контейнеры располагаем по оси z друг за другом, или как будет удобно. Немного о 3D в javaFX: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/javafx-3d-graphics.htm